# Show custom thumbnails in file browser for folders

Tags: image, file-format, file-browser

Is there a way in the Blender file browser to show custom icons or thumbnails for folders?

It bugs me when I'm browsing through textures and I have to open all folders containing a group of PBR textures seperately to get an idea how one looks.

It would help, if there would be a way to preview files like Windows does it (see screenshot), or if there would be a way to set icons manually/via script.

[image: Thumbnail comparison (Windows, Blender)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this isn't possible in Blender for now. The file browser is being revamped for one of the next versions (I think 2.81 or 2.82 if I remember correctly), so maybe it will be a thing then.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I'll check out the file browser rewamp though and see if something like that is planned.

Comment: I've stumbled across this twitter post, maybe you can get in touch with the devs in charge there: https://twitter.com/BillRey/status/1160201393514471424?s=19

Comment: Thanks. I dropped a comment there with a short version of my question. Depending on if and what kind of answer I get, I will try to promote this idea further.